# Entity Framework inherited one to zero to one relationship configuration with fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I can't find an answer by searching through SO questions and by Googling around.

I have a very simple structure:

```
public class Employee
{
   property int Id { get; set; }

   property int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Developer : Employee
{
   property string Level { get; set; }
}
```

and I have two tables for this domain model:

```
create table Employees
(
    Id int not null primary key identity(1, 1),
    Name nvarchar(100) not null
)

create table Developers
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    Level nvarchar(100)
)

alter table Developers 
add constraint FK_Developers_Employees 
foreign key ([Id]) references Employees ([Id])
```

This C# model and SQL Server database schema can not be changed. The scenario is:

1. First add an employee (**One**-employee)
2. This employee is not a developer yet (One-employee-to-**Zero**-developer)
3. Then promote that employee to a developer (One-employee-to-**One**-developer)

How should I configure my `Context` class? I would also appreciate sample code for this scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, Entity Framework requires both entities to have an Id column in order for a 1:1 or 1:0..1 to work.  That means you HAVE to alter the C# model to add an ID column for EF to use it as you want.  There is no way to do this strictly by fluent configuration, since EF requires the physical key on both entities.

Comment: I couldn't solve it even by adding an Id to the `Developer` class. I would really appreciate it, if you provide a *working* sample?

Comment: Both have to have Primary keys, and the second has to also be a foreign key to the first (which you have in your database, but EF has to be configured that way as well).  Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, that's exactly the problem The link you showed to me uses *Aggregation* (or *Composition* I think) type of association. That is, `Developer` class should have a property called `Employee`. But in my case, the type of association is *inheritance*. That's why I've included the association type in question title.

Comment: I see.  Have you tried this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5  here's a better example http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: However, your bigger problem is that you cannot convert an Employee to a Developer if you use TPT, at least not in EF.  You would have to use a sproc or sql command, such as Javad mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this as simple as it seems. You have to delete the first entity from context, clone it in a new object -`Developer` here-, and add the new one to the context.

```
var emp = _context.Employees.Find(id);
_context.Delete(emp);
var dev = new Developer(/* clone from emp */);
_context.Developers.Add(dev);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Which will change the `Id` of employee. However, if you want to avoid this (changing `Id`), you have to use raw SQL - e.g. calling a stored procedure - to add a row to `Developers` and reload the context.

Another option is to set `Id` column by custom, which as you mentioned in Q, it's not possible to change the scheme. So ignore it.

Comment: Dear @Javad_Amiry, this solution is not practical. What if you can't delete the independent entity because of many more relations it has, like `EmployeeFrindgeBenefit` for example? It's a bad design to delete a record, in order to add another record.

Comment: Yep, I know that is a bad idea. But if you want to do everything by EF, it's the only option you have. But as I mentioned, you have some other solutions. Using raw SQL, or event better, using a custom identifier generator e.g. HiLo. My English is too bad :) contact me so we can talk in our language :D

Comment: @SaeedNeamati contact: kavand [dot] ds [at] gmail